# Flutter. How to play: short sound vs long music file?

Tags: audio, flutter

Like the title says, what is the widget or function that plays short sound like an Alarm and long ones like an mp3 file. And what are the extension of those audio files? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this plugin [Audioplayer](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/audioplayer). It's possible to play local and remote audio files.